# Could MPI_Bcast lead to the issue of data uncertainty?

Tags: mpi

If different process broadcast different value to the other processes in the group of a certain communicator,what would happen?

Take the following program run by two processes as an example,

```
int rank, size;
int x;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
if (rank == 0)
{
    x = 0;
    MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (rank==1)
{
    x = 1;
    MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
cout << "Process " << rank << "'s value is:" << x << endl;
MPI_Finalize();
```

I think there could be different possibilities of the printed result at the end of the program. If the process 0 runs faster than process 1, it would broadcast its value earlier than process 1, so process 1 would have the same value with process 0 when it starts broadcasting its value, therefore making the printed value of x both 0. But if the process 0 runs slower than process 1, the process 0 would have the same value as process 1 which is 1 at the end. Does what I described happen actually?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this code is non-conform as not all processes of the communicator call `MPI_Bcast()` with the same root argument (which is explicitly required by the MPI standard). Therefore, the behaviour is undefined: anything can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't understand the MPI_Bcast function well. Actually MPI_Bcast is a kind of MPI collective communication method in which every process that belongs to a certain communicator need to get involve. So for the function of MPI_Bcast, not only the process who sends the data to be broadcasted, but also the processes who receive the broadcasted data need to call the function synchronously in order to achieve the goal of data broadcasting among all participating processes.

In your given program, especially this part:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
   x = 0;
   MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (rank==1)
{
  x = 1;
  MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

I think you meant to let process whose rank is 0 (process 0) broadcasts its value of x to other processes, but in your code, only process 0 calls the MPI_Bcast function when you use the if-else segment. So what do other processes do? For process whose rank is 1 (process 1), it doesn't call the same MPI_Bcast function the process 0 calls, although it does call another MPI_Bcast function to broadcast its value of x (the argument of root is different between those two MPI_Bcast functions).Thus if only process 0 calls the MPI_Bcast function, it just broadcasts the value of x to only itself actually and the value of x stored in other processes wouldn't be affected at all. Also it's the same condition for process 1. As a result in your program, the printed value of x for each process should be the same as when it's assigned initially and  there wouldn't be the data uncertainty issue as you concerned.

Answer (score 1):

`MPI_Bcast` is used primarily so that rank 0 [root] can calculate values and broadcast them so everybody starts with the same values.

Here is a valid usage:

```
int x;

// not all ranks may get the same time value ...
srand(time(NULL));

// so we must get the value once ...
if (rank == 0)
    x = rand();

// and broadcast it here ...
MPI_Bcast(&x,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Notice the difference from your usage. The *same* `MPI_Bcast` call for *all* ranks. The root will do a send and the others will do recv.